# Adding a new link to an existing road shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, road, isochrone

I have an existing road file of Auckland. I wish to add a new road to the existing shapefile so I can calculate a revised distance isochrone. However, when I add the new link, it is ignored by the existing network.

Comment: You'll need to add a bit more pertinent info to get an answer. What specific tool in QGIS are you using? I imagine you need to rebuild the network manually before any updates to your isochrones will take place. The network is a cache of your original shapefile that tends not to be updated without user input as it is computationally expensive

Comment: I am just adding a new line feature to the existing shape file. I don't know how to add new data to the existing road file, which will work. Can you provide any advice or links to how i can rebuild the network with the proposed links i need?